# Python - Statsmodels - Different input types result in different output types?

Tags: python, types, statsmodels, conventions

I was using Statsmodel to train some time series models and found out that the data type of some of the output will be different depending on the input type, while I was expecting the type of output to be independent of the input type.

My question is, is this normal in statsmodels (and in other packages, i.e., sklearn)? If not, what's the normal/standard/convention way to handle such situation?

I have an example below. If I use `pandas.Series` as input, then the output `bse` from statsmodels will be a `pandas.Series`. If the input is a `list`, then the output will be `np.array`.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

x1 = pd.Series([1.5302615469999998,1.130221162,1.059648341,1.246757738,0.98096523,1.173285138,
1.630229825,1.6447988169999999,1.753422,1.7624994719999998,1.60655743,1.7999185709999999,
1.7284643419999999,1.74167109,1.606315199,1.510957898,1.38138611,1.4421003190000001,1.172060761,
0.978149498,0.878831354,0.802660206])

x2 = [s for s in x1]

model1 = ARIMA(x1, order=(1,1,0))
model2 = ARIMA(x2, order=(1,1,0))

model_fit1 = model1.fit(disp=False)
model_fit2 = model2.fit(disp=False)

model_fit1.bse #outputs pandas series
model_fit2.bse #outputs numpy array
```

Answer (score 2):

This is true for all or most models and many functions in statsmodels. It is part of the pandas support.

Pandas Series or DataFrames provide an index and other information like column names for the design matrix, and models and many functions try to preserve it and return a Series or DataFrame with the appropriate index.

Any other types will be converted to numpy arrays (np.asarray), if that is possible, and any additional information that those data structures have will be ignored.

So the rule is, if the user uses pandas, then the code assumes that the user wants matching pandas data structures back.
This could be extended to other data structures besides pandas, but there are currently no plans for supporting datastructures from other packages.